# C# Sql Raw Query to Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a group data in my database like that:

```
Code   ModificationDate
--------------------------
 A     2020/01/02
 A     2020/01/01
 B     2020/01/03
 B     2020/01/01
 C     2020/01/04
 C     2020/01/01
```

And I want to get the value with the most recent `ModificationDate` from each group of codes.

I tried some linq queries, but I always get the same error

> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable'

To workaround it, I wrote this code:

```
var query = _context.Customers.FromSqlRaw(@"
            SELECT t.* FROM(
                  SELECT[Code], MAX([ModificationDate]) as [ModificationDate]
                  FROM[Customers]
                  GROUP BY[Code]
            ) c
            INNER JOIN[Customers] t
            ON t.[Code] = c.[Code] AND t.[ModificationDate] = c.[ModificationDate]");
```

It works fine, but I want to translate it to a linq query that doesn't trigger the mentioned error.

I don't want to use `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` because I have a lot of data and load it into memory is going to be slow.

Comment: Do something like this : db.OrderByDescending(x => x.ModificationDate).GroupBy(x => x.ModificationDate).Selectx => x.First()).ToList();

Comment: It triggers the same error:     .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. :(

Comment: The is something wrong with your model.  Each table in the model should be an Enumerable() object.  right click you model variable db and select Definition to locate the model.

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()` does ***NOT*** load the whole data into memory!

Comment: Then is a good practice to use .AsEnumerable() in this example?

Comment: While `AsEnumerable()` itself does not load the whole data in memory, iterating it (or executing further LINQ to Object queries over it) does, except you stop the iteration earlier. Hence it is better than `ToList()` / `ToArray()`, but still not good in general, taking into account that L2O operators like `OrderBy{Descending}` and `GroupBy` perform full iteration of the source sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i'm using this:

```
IQueryable<Customer> query =
           from c in _context.Customers.GroupBy(a => a.Code).Select(a => a.Max(a => a.ModificationDate))
           from s in _context.Customers
           where c == s.ModificationDate
           select s;
```

This works fine

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs frequently with `GroupBy` in EF core 3/5. In your case there is way to make EF happy by following this query pattern (based on the Chinook sample database, not knowing your class model):

```cs
from c in Customers
from i in c.Invoices.OrderByDescending(i => i.InvoiceDate).Take(1)
select new 
{
    c.LastName,
    i.BillingAddress
}
```

This is even the preferred query pattern, even failing sufficient `GroupBy` support, because (at least in Sql Server, maybe other providers too), EF translates `Take` into the efficient `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` construct in SQL. The LINQ query above is translated to this SQL statement in EF-core 3.1.10:

```
SELECT [c].[LastName], [t0].[BillingAddress]
FROM [Customer] AS [c]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[InvoiceId], [t].[BillingAddress], [t].[BillingCity], [t].[BillingCountry], [t].[BillingPostalCode], [t].[BillingState], [t].[CustomerId], [t].[InvoiceDate], [t].[Total]
    FROM (
        SELECT [i].[InvoiceId], [i].[BillingAddress], [i].[BillingCity], [i].[BillingCountry], [i].[BillingPostalCode], [i].[BillingState], [i].[CustomerId], [i].[InvoiceDate], [i].[Total]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [i].[CustomerId] ORDER BY [i].[InvoiceDate] DESC) AS [row]
        FROM [Invoice] AS [i]
    ) AS [t]
    WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON [c].[CustomerId] = [t0].[CustomerId]
```

It's a bit disappointing, though, that EF doesn't reduce the fields in the subquery according to the properties requested in the LINQ query. That could be achieved by a query like this:

```cs
from c in Customers
from i in c.Invoices.OrderByDescending(i => i.InvoiceDate)
    .Select(i => new { i.BillingAddress, i.BillingCity })
    .Take(1)
select new 
{
    c.LastName,
    i.BillingAddress,
    i.BillingCity
}
```

...unfortunately causing some code repetition.

Comment: This works for collection navigation properties and even manual joins (using  correlated subquery syntax and not `GroupJoin` syntax ), but not for `GroupBy` scenarios with the standard pattern `query.GroupBy(e => KeyExpr(e)).SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy{Descending}(e => OrderExpr(e)).Take(N))`. It really needs [Support ability to select top N of each group #13805](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13805) being implemented. The interesting is that this actually represents `where row_number() over (partition by order by) <= N` pattern.

Comment: @Ivan Yep, I know, and I wonder why EF has made `GroupBy` support so hard for themselves.